# In app purchase is failing first timewith sandbox , works fine next time

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

> Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"
>   UserInfo=0x339120 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes
>   Store}

So I have been trying to resolve this error for last few days. I am logging out logged user from cloud and iTunes from settings app then I click the in app purchase in the app , when it asks me to sign with existing or new user , I click on existing user then I enter correct sandbox credentials in that . It asks the same information once more then It gives me above error.

Strange thing is that this happens with every new sandbox user for first time but when I click on in app button again then it works fine. Can you please guys point me to right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't cause any problem in production. Sandbox is buggy.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've done the standard sanity checks: double-checking your code, confirming your product IDs, comparing your code to the In-App Purchase Programming Guide, etc.

This may be ridiculous, but -- if you're certain your code is correct -- do a hard reset (full wipe) of your iPod (Settings => General => Reset => Erase All Content and Settings). I puzzled over this exact problem for hours -- it turned out my code was correct and the hard reset was the solution.

Comment: I have done checked all these things. Every new sandbox user is failing first time with unknow error. it works when I try again.